# Finding the region of matching image pattern's coordinates on an image using Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to code a small class which will match the given image's portion with another image.

Lets say, I am having a 1024x1024 image, and another image of size 512x512. I want to find the coordinates of the small sized image's matching pattern of portion in the bigger sized image.

Is there any library or framework available for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing which comes to mind is to split your source and target images into segments of equal size and then compare these segments. The result of this operation would be some sort of percentage degree of similarity, where the source segment with the higher percentage usually wins. This technique (I think) is called WISARD or WIZARD (though I can't find anything concrete on the net).

Note, depending on what you are after, it might also be a good idea to remove any colour from the image. Also, like any image comparison process, this process is highly sensitive to any graphical manipulation operation such as skewing and rotating.